# How to initialise an Altair plot

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have some python code to create a plot in altair.

```
# Create dropdown selections
result_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['Major region'].unique().tolist(), name="Local authority: ")
result_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Major region'], bind=result_dropdown, name='Area', init={"Major region": "West Midlands", "variable": "Admissions per 100,000 population: women"})

variable_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=melted_df['variable'].unique().tolist(), name="Category: ")
variable_selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['variable'], bind=variable_dropdown, name='Variable: ')
# Sort the data by 'year' before plotting
sorted_data = melted_df.sort_values(by='Year')
#selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Region'], bind='legend')
# Create the updated Altair plot
chart = alt.Chart(sorted_data).mark_line(size=10).encode(
    x='Year:O',
    y=alt.Y('mean(value):Q', title='Selected Value'),
    #opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2)),

    color='Region:N',
    tooltip=["Region","value", "Year"],
   
).interactive().add_selection(
    result_selection
).transform_filter(
    result_selection
).add_selection(
    variable_selection
).transform_filter(
    variable_selection
).properties(width=400, height=300)

chart
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Which is wrong.

However, if I use the dropdown for another chart and then reselect the initial choice I get the right visualisation. What do I do to make sure the initial choice is presented properly?

This is what it should look like:

[image]